# Grouping steps or concatenating scenarios in Gherkin

Tags: cucumber, bdd, behat, gherkin, scenarios

I'm defining a feature to be used in a BDD workflow with tools such as [Behat](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/#) or [Cucumber](https://cucumber.io), using the [Gherkin](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Gherkin) language. This is the feature definition so far:

```
Feature: Save Resource
    In order to keep interesting resources that I want to view later
    As a user
    I need to be able to save new resources

    Scenario: Saving a new resource
        Given "http://google.com" is a valid link
        When I insert "http://google.com" as the new resource link
        And I insert "Google Search Engine" as the new resource title
        Then I should see a confirmation message with the inserted link and title
        When I accept
        Then I should have 1 additional resource with the inserted link and title

    Scenario: Aborting saving a new resource
        Given "http://google.com" is a valid link
        When I insert "http://google.com" as the new resource link
        And I insert anything as the new resource title
        Then I should see a confirmation message with the inserted link and title
        When I abort
        Then I should have the same number of resources as before

    Scenario: Saving a resource with invalid link
        Given "http://invalid.link" is an invalid link
        When I insert "http://invalid.link" as the new resource link
        And I insert anything as the new resource title
        Then I should see a confirmation message with the inserted link and title
        When I accept
        Then I should see an error message telling me that the inserted link is invalid

    Scenario: Saving a resource with already saved link
        Given "http://google.com" is an already saved link
        When I insert "http://google.com" as the new resource link
        And I insert anything as the new resource title
        Then I should see a confirmation message with the inserted link and title
        When I accept
        Then I should see an error message telling me that the inserted link already exists
```

As you can see, there's a lot of boilerplate repeated in several scenarios. I know I could define a `Background` with a list of steps to be executed before all scenarios, where I could put all the steps up to the confirmation message, but if I did that, I wouldn't be able to distinguish among different links and titles that the user might have inserted.

Is it possible to define a background that is used only for certain, and not all, scenarios? Or maybe to concatenate two scenarios, for example requiring that a certain scenario (that I can reuse) is run before another? Or should I simply keep repeating the boilerplate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following on from Thomas' answer

Your scenarios are complicated and repetitive because each time they are describing 'how' the user interacts with the application. 'How' has no place in scenarios because

1. The details of how you do things are likely to change as you learn more about what you are doing. You don't want to have to change your scenarios every time you change a detail of how you do something
2. Putting how in you scenarios makes them boring, repetitive, difficult to read and expensive to implement.
3. Putting how is your scenarios is generally a way of avoiding doing the real work that scenarios are here for, which is to find out 'why' your are doing something and define elegantly and succinclty 'what' you are trying to achieve.

n.b. there are lots of other reasons

Lets look at how simple your scenarios become when you do this extra bit of work

##Old

```
Scenario: Saving a new resource
    Given "http://google.com" is a valid link
    When I insert "http://google.com" as the new resource link
    And I insert "Google Search Engine" as the new resource title
    Then I should see a confirmation message with the inserted link and title
    When I accept
    Then I should have 1 additional resource with the inserted link and title
```

##New

```
Scenario: Bookmarking
  When I save a bookmark
  Then my bookmark should be saved
```

##Old

```
Scenario: Saving a resource with invalid link
  Given "http://invalid.link" is an invalid link
  When I insert "http://invalid.link" as the new resource link
  And I insert anything as the new resource title
  Then I should see a confirmation message with the inserted link and title
  When I accept
  Then I should see an error message telling me that the inserted link is invalid
```

##New

```
Scenario: Bookmark with invalid link
  When I bookmark with an invalid link
  Then I should see an invalid link error
```

etc.

Note how the new scenarios illustrate so clearly just how little you are doing in terms of adding business value!!

As for your question about backgrounds, if you need two different backgrounds you need two different .feature files. This is a good thing!!

Comment: Thanks for you detailed answer! Keeping Thomas' links as reference, I see how adding a lot of details is distracting and fails to convey the real behaviour of the feature. However, there's also the risk of being too high level and abstract: shouldn't I make examples with real values (in this case real resource data) in my scenarios, to make them concrete? Your suggestion for the Bookmarking scenario, for example, feels a bit abstract, even tautologic, to me.

Comment: Starting with a tautology is actually quite a good thing to do when Cuking. Its a good way of succinctly specifying the happy path, and requires you do one of the hardest and most beneficial things in computing which is to find a name for something (bookmarking in your example). The scenarios would flesh out a little more once you started exploring sad paths and extensions to the functionality e.g. a bookmark created on one device being available on another)

Answer (score 5):

I would consider thinking about what your scenarios are supposed to do. Currently I see scripts that talks about how stuff is done. Almost nothing about what should be done.

Navigation details isn’t really useful for understanding what the system is supposed to do. This is a well known beginners mistake as described in [1] and transcribed in [2].

What you want to do is to push the UI details down the stack. Navigation details lives better in helper methods/classes used by the steps you implement. A page object is one way of hiding navigation from the Scenarios.

Some of your duplication will disappear when you get rid of the navigation details. The remaining duplication might be acceptable for readability reasons.

Remember that understanding the scenarios are much more important than a bit of duplication.

[1] https://cucumber.io/blog/2016/05/09/cucumber-antipatterns

[2] http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2016/06/22/cucumber-antipatterns

Comment: Thanks, very interesting links! I was assuming that the navigation (in this case the presence of confirmation/error messages) was important to be agreed upon with stakeholders, and as such it deserved being defined inside scenarios. If I put it in the lower level implementation, stakeholders won't know about it until prototypes or MVPs are built, unless they agreed upon an UI design, in which case there would be two different sources for the definition of features: the scenarios and the UI design. Would this be acceptable?

Comment: UI details may be important, but most business people operate at cloud altitude. That is from a very high perspective. They usually don't care about a confirmation dialog. Hence, such a detail is not important for what we are trying to achieve that is valuable for the business.